# Knockout custom mapping for nested objects

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a JSON object like:

```
{
    id:"a",
    type:"simple",
    children:[
        {
            id:"a.1",
            type:"simple",
            children:[
                {
                    id:"a.1.1",
                    type:"simple",
                },
                {
                    id:"a.1.2",
                    type:"simple",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id:"a.2",
            type:"simple",
        },
        {
            id:"a.2",
            type:"simple",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use the knockout mapping plugin to create a custom selected property for all children objects like this:

```
{
    id:"a",
    type:"simple",
    children:[
        {
            id:"a.1",
            type:"simple",
            selected:true,
            children:[
                {
                    id:"a.1.1",
                    type:"simple",
                    selected:true
                },
                {
                    id:"a.1.2",
                    type:"simple",
                    selected:true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id:"a.2",
            type:"simple",
            selected:true
        },
        {
            id:"a.2",
            type:"simple",
            selected:true
        }
    ]
}
```

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
getMapping : function() {
    var childModle = function(data) {
        data.selected = false;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
        };
        var mapping = {
            "children" : {
                create : function(options) {
                    return new childModle(options.data);
                }
            }
        };
    return mapping;
},

var mapping =  this.getMapping();
var mappedModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping);
```

This only works for the top level children. The 2-n level children are not created using my mapping.

*** My model can have an infinite amount of nested levels ***

My question is how can I make the children create apply for all nested children?

Comment: You would want to pass the mapping options into the `ko.mapping.fromJS` call that you are making inside the `childModle` constructor.

Comment: Ahh, yes that makes sense. Thanks a bunch. This is my first post. Do i need to do something for you?

Comment: I will move this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You would want to pass the mapping options into the `ko.mapping.fromJS` call that you are making inside the `childModle` constructor function.